# train['Gender'].fillna(train['Gender'].mode()[0], inplace=True)

Tags: python, data-science

```
train['Gender'].fillna(train['Gender'].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```

I got this code in one of my basic data science course. I wanted to understand, what is the significance of "[0]" after mode() in this. I would really appreciate the answer.
Thanks!

Comment: the ```mode()``` function returns a list. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: Thanks, Nick! So, the [0] is for accessing the first element of the list returned by the mode?

Answer (score 2):

[Mode documentaion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html)

The `mode()` return 2 value, first is mode value second is count. So `train['Gender'].mode()[0]` means get the mode value of `train['Gender']`.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `[0]` means that the thing before it (`mode()` in this case) is a collection, a list, an array, ..., and you are taking the first element.

In case you need more information, you need to include the rest of the source code (preferably by editing your question), explaining the exact meaning of the mentioned objects.